# how to run coffeescript with web storm

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm

I'm having trouble running a coffeescript configuration with webstorm.  If I enable the coffeescript plugin in the run configuration I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/coffee app.coffee
env: node: No such file or directory
```

I tried the solution in the support forums of adding my path variable to the environment variables but still no fix.

[image]

Comment: Looks like environment issue, try adding `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH` in the **Environment variables field**.

Answer (score 1):

Because, the executable file is not found yet.

Goto Terminal and type: `echo NODE_PATH` or `echo $NODE_PATH` to see where is the file.

On windows, C:\Users[YOUR_USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee

So, use Spotlight search tool to have a look at /usr/local/npm ..... or somewhere else.

Comment: I did, it was /usr/bin/coffee but putting it in didn't help.  Updating to the latest coffeescript version, updating webstorm to latest and rebooting seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: I use sublime text 2 and plugin called "better coffeescript". The console window in webstorm is too small...

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass **absolute path** to your app.js. Webstorm sometimes mess with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I had a lot of trouble with this, you must find your "coffee" file. BTW, this could help you too.

#### After you installed Node.js and installed the CoffeScript plugin:

1. **Download** the last version (or source) from **[CoffeeScript.org](http://coffeescript.org/)**
2. **Unzip** it wherever you want. In my case I unzipped the **jashkenas-coffeescript-1.10.0-0-gf26d33d.tar.gz** on  **D:\tools\**
3. **Check 'Run with CoffeeScript plugin'**
4. **Target** the coffee executable on menu **'Run > Edit Configurations...'**:

[image]

Comment: Why I can't see ***Run with CoffeeScript plugin*** checkbox?